# Find $\delta>0$ where $f(x)<f(X_0)<f(y)$ when $f^\prime(x_0)>0$ for some $x_0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to find some $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)<f(x_0)<f(y)$ whenever $x_0-\delta<x<x_0<y<x_0+\delta$ if $f^\prime(x_0)>0$ for some point $x_0$ in the interior of the domain of $f$?

I found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2568616/604136), but I am still confused how to find $\delta$.

My attempt:

*Proof*

Assume not. That is, assume $\forall\delta>0, f(x)\nless f(x_0)\nless f(y)$ whenever $x_0-\delta<x<x_0<y<x_0+\delta$ if $f^\prime(x_0)>0$ for some point $x\in$dom($f$). Then $f$ must be nonincreasing. So the $f^\prime(x_0)\leq 0$. But $f^\prime(x_0)>0$, so we have a contradiction....
but this is obviously incomplete and perhaps even wrong.

How do I find a $\delta>0$ where all the conditions are satisfied? Also, does this mean $f$ is increasing in the interval $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$? I say no because the function can switch directions at $x$ and $y$ so that $x_0-\delta>x_0+\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

By the definitions of derivative and limit, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - x_0|<\delta$ implies $\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} > 0$ since $f'(x_0)>0$. Now treat the cases when $x<x_0$ and $x>x_0$.

Comment: @Izralbu I still don't quite understand. How will this lead to $f(x)<f(x_0)<f(y)$?

Comment: Note that $x - x_0$ and $f(x) - f(x_0)$ must be both positive or both negative since their quotient is positive. If $x < x_0$ then $f(x) < f(x_0)$ else if $y > x_0$ then $f(y) > f(x_0)$.